# как найти индекс первого вхождения в строке

Tags: c#

Выполняю задание где надо найти индекс первого вхождения в строке с помощью циклов(do..while,for,while)в задании есть юнит тесты. Ниже пример с помощью do..while

```
        public static int GetIndexOfChar(string str, char value, int startIndex, int count)
         {       
        if (str is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(str));
        if (startIndex < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(startIndex), "startIndex is less than zero");
        if (startIndex > str.Length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(startIndex), "startIndex is greater than str.Length");
        if (count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count), "count is less than zero");
        if (startIndex + count > str.Length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count), "startIndex + count > str.Length");

        int currentCharIndex = startIndex + str.Length - 52;
        if (currentCharIndex < 0)
            return -1;

        do
        {
            char currentChar = str[currentCharIndex];
            if (currentChar == value)
            {
                return currentCharIndex;
            }

            currentCharIndex++;
        }
        while (currentCharIndex < count);

        return -1;
    }
```

Возникла проблема метод не считает значения теста(str,value,startIndex,count) где (str,'a',1,26)(str,'b',2,26)(str,'z',26,26).Этот метод получается начинает считать с начального индекса(startIndex) сравнивает каждое значение с вхождением (value) и в случае первого совпадения возвращает его значение, но не могу понять почему возвращает -1, вроде бы счетчик(count) покрывает значение ?
Также знаю что можно использовать метод str.IndexOf(), но по заданию им пользоваться нельзя
Объясните плиз в чем проблема

Comment: А что это вот такое: `int currentCharIndex = startIndex + str.Length - 52;` Конечно тут получается отрицательное значение, если длина строки + стартовый индекс меньше 52. Что это за число вообще 52?

Comment: @CrazyElf, это английский алфавит большими буквами и маленькими

Comment: @CrazyElf да забыл про это , это длина строки равна 52 , сделано специально чтобы получить отрицательное значение чтобы пройти еще один тест ("",'a',0,0). Если есть мысли как его сделать иначе, или обойтись без этого подскажите

Comment: удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot в принципе да , решение рабочее, только щас пытаюсь понять как сделать так чтобы он прекращал искать в случае если строка не содержит значения , и останавливался на последнем значении count .Крч по идее все просто искать столько раз сколько показывает сount если нашел вернуть значение если не нашел то вернуть минус один ,начинать отсчет со startIndex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что-то вы перемудрили.

```cs
public static int GetIndexOfChar(string str, char value, int startIndex, int count)
{
    int endIndex = Math.Min(str.Length, startIndex + count);
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        if (value == str[i])
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Можно подобное для строки сделать

```cs
public static int GetIndexOf(string str, string value, int startIndex, int count)
{
    int endIndex = Math.Min(str.Length, startIndex + count) - value.Length + 1;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < value.Length; j++)
        {
            if (value[j] != str[i + j])
               break;
        }
        if (j == value.Length)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: a все разобрался вот этот метод Math.Max поменять на Math.Min ,                                                           
  int endIndex = Math.Min(str.Length, startIndex + count); и тогда все заработает как надо спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: @lbraga_kh точно, исправил, спасибо.